# RxJS Observable append new emitted values to existing ones instead of replacing them

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

What I'm trying to achieve is having an Observable that adds more data to it every time a new event is triggered. The scenario is as follows:

Say we have an `elementsService` with `getElements(pageNo: number)` method that does an http call to retrieve some elements.

1. On page load, have an observable that retrieves the first page.

```
@Component({
  template: '<div>{{ elements$ | async }}</div>'
})
export class MyComponent {
  page: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(0);
  elements$: Observable<any> = this.page.pipe(
    mergeMap((page) => _service.getElements(page))
  );

  constructor(private _service: Service) {}
  // ...
}
```

Assume first result is `elements = [ e1, e2 ]`

2. After some time, a new page event is emitted

```
export class MyComponent {
  // ...
  onPageChange(pageNo: number): void {
    this.page.next(pageNo);
  }
}
```

The next page will result in `elements = [ e3, e4 ]`, which means the original values `e1` and `e2` are gone. How can I change this such that elements `e3` and `e4` are appended to the previous Observable result instead of replacing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`scan`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/scan) operator to accumulate results like this:

```js
  elements$: Observable<any> = this.page.pipe(
    mergeMap((page) => _service.getElements(page)),
    scan((all, elements) => all.concat(elements), [])
  );
```

Each time `scan` receives an emission, it will run the function and emit the result.

```js
(all, elements) => all.concat(elements)
```

- `elements` is the incoming emission (*received from the `_service.getElements()` call*).
- `all` is the previously computed value. (*or the "seed value" for the initial run*)